# Ternary Flags? Or possibly cancelling flags

Tags: 7, flags

In my Drupal site, users can be in 1 of 3 states. They will always be in one of these three states. This would be easy to do if the flag module could have three states. However, it only has 2. Is there a flag add on that allows for three states? Could I potentially have 3 flags that, when selected, cancel the others out? Or will I have to write my own module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not available in the Flag module (as you already know) and won't be available in the future ([Issue: Flag States](http://drupal.org/node/671808)).  I have not seen an add-on module that will allow you to do this either.

An easy way would be to use [Flag](http://drupal.org/project/flag) with [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules).  You would have to create multiple flags to use, and when a user flags one of the states, have set rules to unflag the other 2 states.

Another option would be to write a custom module.  Maybe even utilize the [Voting API](http://drupal.org/project/votingapi)

Answer (score 0):

checkout the [rate](http://drupal.org/project/rate) module, they have an "emotions" option where you can specify your different states.